# How do Catholics understand the gathering of Jews in Isaiah 43:5–6?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, prophecy, israel, isaiah

[Isaiah 43:5–6](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=isaiah+43%3A5-6&version=ESV) reads:

> <sup>5</sup> Fear not, for I am with you;
>         from the east I will bring back your offspring,
>         from the west I will gather you.
>   <sup>6</sup> I will say to the north: Give them up!
>         and to the south: Do not hold them!
>   Bring back my sons from afar,
>         and my daughters from the ends of the earth: [NABRE]

This seems to indicate a gathering of all Jews back to the Land of Israel.  I'd like to know the Catholic understanding of these verses, in particular:

- Is this something that will happen?
- Are we talking about the geographic land of Israel?
- Is there a deeper meaning behind it?

How do Catholics interpret the gathering of Jews in these verses?

Comment: Note that Isaiah was speaking to _all_ of Israel, not only to Jews (tribe of Judah).